# How to grep a string in a file that begins and ends with two specific characters?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file of URLs and I want to grep the URLs that have parameters.

I'm able to grep URLs that contain substrings that begin with '?' and end with '=':

```
grep '?[a-z0-9]*=' foobar.txt
```

How do I also grep substrings that begin with '&' and end with '='?
I tried:

```
grep -E '?[a-z0-9]*=|&[a-z0-9]*=' foobar.txt
```

But, that does not work.

Also, how do I include special characters into the regex, for parameters that have '_' or '-' in them?

Comment: You need to use positive lookahead and positive lookbehind and the result regex could be: `(?=\?).*(?<=\=)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
grep -E '\?[^?=]*=|&[^&=]*=' foobar.txt
```

You select POSIX ERE with `-E`, and that's why the question mark needs escaping.

You match anything between `?` and `=` with `[^?=]*`.